Why is .net expression tree compilation blocking?
I have a legacy ASP.NET application built on .Net Framework 4.8 and running on Azure on an App Service instance. Today I was profiling it in production using the Application Insights Profiler and noticed that for some web requests a lot of time (150-1600ms) is spent while blocking in the code that creates and compiles an expression tree. According to the profiling results, the blocking occurs in the System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate() method which, in turn, is called by System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(). I couldn't replicate this condition on my local PC. It seems to occur in production only.

I drilled down into the Compile() method and got the following picture:

I wonder why on the earth the mentioned method may be blocking? Is this a false positive and the problem is actually in something else?

I've found the source code of the method where blocking occurs, and noticed that it takes a lock. It answered all the questions.

I've found the source code of the class where blocking occurs (System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod) and noticed that it takes a lock on itself. This prompted the theory that the way how expressions are used in the application causes competition for the lock. It answers all the questions.
